# There's a way to change a React component property for react-modal that is already set on the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I have the following component:

```
const ModalWrapper = props => {
    return (
        <Modal
            isOpen={true}
            ariaHideApp={false}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Modal>
    )
};
```

I'm using this modal in other file:

```
import ModalWrapper from '../components/CModal/ModalWrapper';

return (
<ModalWrapper
  isOpen={this.state.showModal}
  onRequestClose={this.handleCloseModal}
>
```

so, as in the component: `isOpen` will be always true, and I'm passing the `showModal` state, which will change according with the actions on my file.. there is some way in which I can change or override this isOpen method through my file?

Comment: `isOpen={props.isOpen}`

Comment: @EmileBergeron thx for the comment, is there a way to do something like this from the file which I'm importing the ModalWrapperl?

Comment: It's unclear what's the issue exactly (you should include a [mcve]) though you're already passing the state properly with `<ModalWrapper isOpen={this.state.showModal}`